# convert in to json array and write to a json file

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

here is the result of mysql query array output (`var_dump($array)`),i want to convert this array in json array and write in to json file

```
 $object1 = new stdClass();
$object1->value = "6422";
$object1->date = "2017-03-03";

$object2 = new stdClass();
$object2->value = "700";
$object2->date = "2017-03-18";

$array = [
    $object1,
    $object2
];
```

i want to convert this array in to json array,and write the json array into json file

`$jsonEvents=json_encode($array); file_put_contents('./data/events.json',$jsonEvents);` But this code not works for me

`var_dump($jsonEvents);` gives me `string(4) "null"` result,But there is data on `$array`

Comment: do you have write permission?

Comment: Yep..777 permission given-@vSugumar

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: @JensV: What!?!? Objects are JSON encode-able.

Comment: "But this code not works for me" does not tell us what is not working and just lets us guess. Have you debugged the code? Is the array converted, is the file/directory present, are permission set,
 do you have any errors or warning?

Comment: Actually , i didn't get error messages,But events.json didn't rewrite-@nerdlyist

Comment: i get null on the json file ,but there is data before writing to the json file @nerdlyist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I created your structure artificially like this:

```
<?php

$object1 = new stdClass();
$object1->value = "6422";
$object1->date = "2017-03-03";

$object2 = new stdClass();
$object2->value = "700";
$object2->date = "2017-03-18";

$arr = [
    $object1,
    $object2
];
```

and following code:

```
$jsonEvents = json_encode($arr);
var_dump($jsonEvents);
```

gives me:

```
string(74) "[{"value":"6422","date":"2017-03-03"},{"value":"700","date":"2017-03-18"}]"
```

which seems to be correct. Now, I also invoked following:

```
file_put_contents('events.json', $jsonEvents);
```

and it created for me file. In system, I see:

```
jedrzej@jedrzej-UX303LB ~ $ ls -l | grep json
-rw-rw-r--  1 jedrzej jedrzej      74 Mar 27 19:17 events.json
jedrzej@jedrzej-UX303LB ~ $ cat *.json
[{"value":"6422","date":"2017-03-03"},{"value":"700","date":"2017-03-18"}]
```

So this is behavior one could expect. One thing that could go wrong is the destination directory where you try to write output. And:

1. you may not have write permissions on this directory
2. this directory may not exist

in any case, you should obtain PHP warning which will say something like:

> ... failed to open stream: ...

Comment: Ya..this code works...But i didn't find any diffrence from my code

Comment: IIs there  any diffrence in case of codeigniter frame work?

Comment: I don't think so. json_encode(), and file_put_contents() are native php functions.